# in の前に複数の変数がある for 文の意味

Tags: python

下記のようなinの前にふたつ関数？があるようなfor文はどういう意味でしょうか？

```
for ax, img in zip(axes.ravel(), digits.images):
    ax.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`zip`関数は2つの配列を同時にインクリメントしながら変数を返す関数です。
ここではfor文を最初に通るとき、`ax = axes.ravel()[0]`と`img = digits.images[0]`を格納し、次に通るとき`ax = axes.ravel()[1]`と`img = digits.images[1]`を格納するという意味を持ちます。
[参考記事](http://python.civic-apps.com/zip-enumerate/)

```
ax = [1, 2, 3]
ay = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for (x, y) in zip(ax, ay):
  print(x, y)
#出力結果
#1 a
#2 b
#3 c
```

Comment: 関数が返すものは変数ではなく値だと思います。

Answer (score 9):

２つ組の第１要素を`ax`に、第２要素を`img`に代入するという意味です。（`zip(axes.ravel(), digits.images)`が２つ組のイテレータとなっています。）`ax`と`img`に当たるものは関数とは限らないです。

[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)では

> この操作は、シーケンスのアンパック (sequence unpacking) とでも呼ぶべきもので、

と説明されています。

また`for`に限らず、代入の左辺でも同じ書き方が出来ます。

```
In [1]: x,y = (6,7)

In [2]: x*y
Out[2]: 42
```